# Extjs Window Default Close Button

Tags: extjs, extjs4, window, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a button inside a panel that once clicked will call out a child window. I already created it and there are already items inside it. Once the child window is opened the parent panel will be disabled.

Inside the child window I have a Button that closes the window which will then enables the parent panel.

```
  childWindow.close();
  parent.enable();
```

My problem is the default close button on the Window on the upper right side of the window. If I click it it, I cannot enable the parent panel. it stays disabled, because of course I disabled it.

How do I enable the parent panel once it is closed using the default close button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a listener to the [close](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-event-close) event of the "child" window inside your "main" window. The listener will work, even if it is disabled. In the following example I assume that the win ref is a reference of your "main" window while "child" is the one of your child.

```
openWin: function(child) {
    child.on('close', reactivate, this);
    child.show();
    this.disable();
},
reactivate: function() {
    this.enable();
}
```

Comment: tried it and it does not work.... can I do it like child.on('close', function() {win.enable()}) I dont know if that correct or what is the correct way of doing it. I tried that though does not work either.

Comment: @oneofakind Well, it was just a example... I've edited it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want disable everything behind the window, use the **modal** config of **Ext.window.Window**

> modal : Boolean
>
> True to make the window modal and mask everything
>   behind it when displayed, false to display it without restricting
>   access to other UI elements.
>
> Defaults to: false